# Command line is prompting for password, cannot send password using java eclipse

Tags: java, process, cmd, runtime.exec

I have a program that i am running and it brings up the command prompt screen, i give it my arguments, but then it asks for a password. I send it a password but i get an error, thinking the password is part of the previous arguments, here is some of my code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"" + CD + AND + Keytool + Genkey + Keyalg + Keysize + Alias + Validity + Keystore +  "/K && " + Password);
```

The error is "Illegal Option password"

Any Ideas?

I think i need to use a outputstreamwriter but I am not quite sure how.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just printing the output from the string additions, and see if that looks right? I suggest you start there.

Comment: And I am convinced your password is `password`. Now I am going to hack you :)

Comment: Yes, it looks right to me, i had to add a space before the 2nd K, but it looks fine to me.  Still prompts me with the illegal options error

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to terminate the open quote?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"" + CD + AND + Keytool + Genkey + Keyalg + Keysize + Alias + Validity + Keystore +  "/K \" && " + Password);
```

Or even after the password, maybe

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"" + CD + AND + Keytool + Genkey + Keyalg + Keysize + Alias + Validity + Keystore +  "/K && " + Password + "\"");
```

Comment: The first one kind of worked, it prompted me for the password

Comment: I think you should put everything inside `exec` into a string, print it and see if it's valid.

Comment: I checked to see and it is valid

Comment: Would you mind showing that to us? You can mask the password :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Remove the password from the code
2. Enter the password when it tells you to

Comment: Yes, i would like to do that programmatically though

Comment: Is doing it programmatically even possible?

Comment: Even if you do it, it will check again for consistency, it's the way that the security mechanisms in standard platforms work. so no need for including passwords through coding, for better performance practices!